# Можно ли унаследовать модель из backend от общей модели в common?

Tags: php, yii

Правильно ли будет так делать? У меня есть модель Photos в common с методом allPhotos(), который будет использоваться и в console и в backend. Также в backend есть отдельная модель Photos. Можно ли вместо того, чтобы в контроллере бекенда обращаться к двум моделям Photos, унаследовать модель бекенда от модели в коммон, и потом обращаться только к бекендовской модели?

Answer (score 1):

Да можно. Но одинаковые методы буду переназначены дочерним классом. Если потребуется использовать методы основного класса к ним придётся обращаться отдельно.